# Watermark video by ffmpeg and hardware accelerator

Tags: ffmpeg, nvidia, watermark, hardware-acceleration, video-watermarking

I use a p4000 card and ffmpeg with all requirements (driver , toolkit , cuda compile)
I want to put watermark on the video by this command

```
./bin/ffmpeg -hwaccel cuvid -c:v h264_cuvid -i input.mp4 -i input.png -filter_complex "overlay=10:10" -c:v h264_nvenc output.mp4
```

but I encounter this error

```
Impossible to convert between the formats supported by the filter 'graph 0 input from stream 0:0' and the filter 'auto_scaler_0'
    Error reinitializing filters!
    Failed to inject frame into filter network: Function not implemented
    Error while processing the decoded data for stream #1:0
```

Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-hwaccel cuvid
```

Mean that decoded frame will go to hw encoder directly (not copy in system memory), so at this time it's impossible to add filters to decoded frame. Try remove -hwaccel cuvid, but speed will be slow. 
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HWAccelIntro#CUDACUVIDNVDEC